# Get Won, Tie, Lost Results on a Score Table

Tags: jquery, html-table, compare

Dynamic data/tables printed from the DB. Need to get how many times have **the teams** WON, TIED, LOST. Super new to jQuery and no clue what to start coding with (?!). I was thinking of first getting the row where Chelsea appears, then comparing scores, using arrays to store W, T, L — and printing the results at the end (?).

**This is what the table looks like:**

```
<table>
<tr id="12">
   <td class="238 ekipi_1">Chelsea</td>
   <td class="231 ekipi_2">ManU</td>
   <td class="goals_238">4</td>
   <td class="goals_231">2</td>
</tr>

<tr id="13">
   <td class="242 ekipi_1">Reading</td>
   <td class="238 ekipi_2">Chelsea</td>
   <td class="goals_242">3</td>
   <td class="goals_238">3</td>
</tr>

<tr id="16">
   <td class="251 ekipi_1">Swansea</td>
   <td class="238 ekipi_2">Chelsea</td>
   <td class="goals_251">5</td>
   <td class="goals_238">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The result would be:**

> ```
>           W   T   L
>
> Chelsea | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> Reading | 0 | 1 | 0 |
> ManU    | 0 | 0 | 1 |
> ```

Any tips for a head start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: or maybe do all that stuff server side with the data you have and render it , instead of trying to parse the dom ?

Comment: That table wouldn't look like that. It would have rows like `Chelsea | ManU | 4 | 2` and `Reading | Chelsea | 3 | 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Read the initial data and build the Object you can do this..

```
    var teams = {
    "Chelsea": {"W": 0, "T": 0, "L": 0},
    "ManU": {"W": 0, "T": 0, "L": 0},
    "Reading": {"W": 0, "T": 0, "L": 0},
    "Swansea": {"W": 0, "T": 0, "L": 0}
};

$('table tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var team1 = $this.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var team2 = $this.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var score1 = $this.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var score2 = $this.find('td:eq(3)').text();

    if(+score1 === +score2){
        teams[team1]["T"] =  +teams[team1]["T"] +1; 
        teams[team2]["T"] =  +teams[team2]["T"]+1; 
    }  
    else if(+score1 > +score2){
        teams[team1]["W"] =  +teams[team1]["W"]+1; 
        teams[team2]["L"] =  +teams[team2]["L"]+1; 
    }
    else{
        teams[team1]["L"] =  +teams[team1]["L"]+1; 
        teams[team2]["W"] =  +teams[team2]["W"]+1; 
    }        
});

// Print the data

$.each(teams, function(key,value){
    var $clone = $('#template');
    $clone.find('.team').html(key);
    $clone.find('.score:eq(0)').html(value["W"]);
    $clone.find('.score:eq(1)').html(value["T"]);   
    $clone.find('.score:eq(2)').html(value["L"]);
    $('#output').append($clone.html());
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rd4Y6/4/)**

You can read the **teams object** and print it out once you are done..

Comment: Thanks Sushanth / as I'm new to jQuery, how would I go about printing  the table as the example from my question (ie. W|T|L) // apologies for being a complete noob.

Comment: Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2Wbx/1/) with printing out the table.

Comment: Hi @Sushanth-- the code above works perfectly fine. There are few last things I'm trying to achieve and now I have two various bits of code. This link: http://borozani.com/tabelat/premier-league shows you the end product as it should work. (The last table below: Standings (jQuery print)) is the code you've helped me with, though I can't find a way to print/bring everything on the table above. (There are few tasks I've assigned to myself right below the first table.) // There are times in the beginning of the season where not all teams play right away & all teams have to figure on the table.

Comment: Also @Sushanth-- on the jQuery I've used to print Games Played + Goals Given, I use dynamic data to target each < td > based on the team_id on the table in DB // this helped me a lot while generating dynamic variables in jQuery. (View Source on the link above to see what I mean exactly)

Comment: @OctoberEleven .. Thats good to hear.. You can create the initial team object on the fly without knowing the team names.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth-- I will continue trying building upon your code.